# Delayed baggage is here but not available to pick up

Tags: air-travel, luggage, air-france

I just flew Milan (MXP) - Paris (CDG) - Boston (BOS) with Air France and once landed in BOS, I got the news that my baggage "didn't make it" and that I should have claimed a missing baggage on the airline website.

After the claim I have been able to track my baggage, which was stuck in Paris and got to Boston one day after trough Amsterdam (AMS) on a Delta flight. The flight AMS-BOS landed but there is no news regarding my baggage, even though it should be in Boston at the moment.

How long does it usually take for the baggage to be available for pick-up or delivery? I called the company and they told me to wait but I am quite impatient since all my clothing are in that baggage. Should I just wait until I hear from them or is there any other way to verify where my baggage actually is and go pick it up?

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me for it to take some time for the bag to actually make it to the baggage office, and my experience is they will usually arrange delivery for you instead of holding it for pickup. You could try calling the airport at 1-800-23-LOGAN and seeing if the airport operator can connect you to the office that handles lost bags for Air France at BOS, which would get you in touch with the specific office that can help confirm the status of your bag and what's being done to get it to you.

Comment: Although never in Boston, I had similar experience several times and the baggage would be delivered either the same or next day after it arrived. Unless it gets stuck in customs.

Comment: Asking a question on this, does luggage coming from outside the USA (that ends up being unaccompanied through no fault of the owner) need to go through a special customs process where it can only be released to the owner in person, rather than the USA domestic way of just getting it delivered without additional inspection?

Comment: @Milwrdfan It came from outside the US but there was no issue with custom. They could deliver the luggage to me without needing me to go there and get it.

Comment: @ZachLipton Thanks for the suggestion! I tried calling the airport but the guy who picked up was quite mad I called because he said that is an issue for which airlines are responsible and not the airport and suggested me not to call again. Not the most polite person.

Answer (score 2):

Typically this takes only a day or two. If it's longer than that and there is no update on the website, I would call.

Obviously nothing is going to happen today, because of the Blizzard

Answer (score 2):

The issue is solved but I will give an update for anyone needing in the future.

So the main issue was that my flight was Air France, while the baggage has been sent with a Delta flight. Thus, the baggage was at the Delta baggage office for almost a week before they sent it to Air France that then sent it to the delivery company.

The system does not work great in general since both companies were not able to give me clear updates or speed up the process at all. The baggage got to Boston one day after me but I got it at home after a week of it sitting at the airport.

I guess the only thing is hoping that the company will send the baggage on a flight of theirs, otherwise you are going to be waiting.